# What legal avenues are there for a foreign national to aid a US election?

Tags: united-states, election, senate, foreign-interference

putting it bluntly: suppose I as a Belgian citizen want to help the Democratic party win the 2 Georgia Runoff elections because it would help the entire world to have an undivided US government (for example better climate goals), but without risking legal problems for either me or any of the US politicians involved. I already know that I can't be donating money because the US law explicitly bans US campaigns from knowingly accepting foreign donations. I know that the easiest option in fact is to just stay out of this entirely to avoid any semblance of interference entirely, but it already felt so frustrating to have to sit through the Presidential election race without being able to impact such a globally important event.

Is there anything I as a Belgian citizen can do to help the Democratic party win the 2 US Senate runoff elections?

Comment: The [Internet Research Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Research_Agency) posted ads on Facebook.

Comment: If you can become a permanent resident of the US you can donate even though you are an alien, but that is surely not the answer you're looking for.